# Image compression web app,can you suggest steps to achieve it

Tags: php, matlab, image-processing, compression, online-storage

I'm building a web app,which actually does image compression for the user's image,I want to ask, the image compression algortithm's that we implement in MATLAB like Kekre's Algorithm,zero tree algo,predictive encoding, is it possible to implement them in php.

So, can anybody suggest ,how can I achieve those things in php, or provide me some reference links,which can help me to build a online Compression tool.
or if anybody done anything like converting program logic of image manipulation from matlab to php. I  have a high level DFD of my tool is: [you can find it here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2025503/college%20Projects/BE%20PROJECT/project%20flow.JPG)

Comment: PHP's turing-complete, so you can implement anything you want, including PHP itself.

Comment: I do not have that kind of skill set, but I could recommended Mathematica for Java or .Net server side. Php one might aswell exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is slow for such processing. I recommend that you implement the core of you algorithm in C++ or similar. Then you call the core processing from PHP in a similar way like some web applications call ImageMagic in background to process images.

Comment: so ,is there any ready core image processing lirary available on net,for php. which may include algorithm's like kekre's algo,vector quantization,DWT, and all.